# How can I set the axis for ScalingFunction in a BarChart?

Tags: graphics, plotting

Why is the scaling function being applied to the wrong axis? Here, the log ticks are on the Y axis, but they should be on the X axis:

```
BarChart[{0.1, 1, 10, 100}, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
 ChartStyle -> 45, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", BarOrigin -> Left, 
 Frame -> True]
```

Comment: It looks like `ScalingFunctions` is affected by `Frame -> True` (possible bug). If you remove `Frame -> True`, then the log ticks are applied to the x axis as expected.

Comment: @rm-rf That qualifies as a good answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a bug in how `ScalingFunctions` works. It is affected by the `Frame -> True` option, and if you remove it, then the scaling is applied correctly to the x-axis.

```
BarChart[{0.1, 1, 10, 100}, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
    ChartStyle -> 45, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

Attempts to reintroduce the frame using `Show[..., Frame -> True]` also fail, so if you need the frame, you might have to roll your own.

Comment: So how would we report this? Are there wolfram experts who would fix it here?

Comment: I'll dig into this later today (it might not entirely be a bug). `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"` applies it to both axes (you can easily hide the y-ticks). In fact, the x-axis is transformed too... the values you see are `Log@` of your values. It's just not displayed in a convenient way. If you want log to the base 10, you can use the undocumented `ScalingFunctions -> "Log10"` and the x-ticks are correctly displayed from -1 to 2. The trick is then to get it to display as `10^x`. There are several ad-hoc ways of doing it, but I'm trying to see if it can be done within the function itself.